# How to read the data from lParam (the pointers value)

Tags: winapi, callback

I made a small application that sends text to notepad via SendMessage and EM_REPLACESEL.

Now I’m trying to hook notepad to get the EM_REPLACESEL value (the lParam value and in this case the “GET THIS TEXT” text).

[image: Picture from Spy++]

**EDIT**: See this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8scNL.jpg

The hook works fine, my problem is to listen for the EM_REPLACESEL message and grab the value from the lParam.

This code works fine, when messages are sent to notepad:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    Beep (2000,100);
    return(CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

So now I want to intercept EM_REPLACESEL messages. This **do not** work:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (nCode == EM_REPLACESEL)
    {
        Beep (2000,100);
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

1)  How to listen for the EM_REPLACESEL message?

2)  When I have gotten the message how to grab the lParam value and e.g. show it in a MessageBox. Something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (nCode == EM_REPLACESEL)
    {
        MSG *lpMsg;
        lpMsg = (MSG *) lParam;
        MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)lpMsg,NULL,NULL);
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EM_REPLACESEL` is a sent message, not a posted message, so you need to use a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook instead of a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook, eg:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        CWPSTRUCT* cwps = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (cwps->message == EM_REPLACESEL) {
            Beep (2000,100);
            // etc..
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

... = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, ...),
```

Comment: Excellent, Remy. It works. Thanks. How do I then show the value in a message box? This just give rubbish : MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)cwps,NULL,NULL); ?

Comment: `CWPSTRUCT` is a structure, not a string. You cannot typecast it to a `LPCWSTR`. To extract the text from an `EM_REPLACESEL` message, you need to typecast the `CWPSTRUCT::lParam` field instead: `if (IsUnicodeWindow(cwps->hwnd)) MessageBoxW(NULL, (LPWSTR)cwps->lParam, ...); else MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPSTR)cwps->lParam, ...);`

Answer (score 2):

Your [GetMsgProc() callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is coded wrong.  Carefully read the linked MSDN page to see what the arguments of the callback mean.  The *nCode* argument is **not** the message number, it specifies whether or not you should process the message.  You want to use the passed *lParam* to recover the message that you intercepted.  Make it look similar to this instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        MSG* pmsg = (MSG*)lParam;
        if (pmsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            Beep (2000,100);
            // etc..
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Do note that you appear to use the WH_GETMESSAGE hook.  It only works for messages that are posted to the message queue with PostMessage().  But EM_REPLACESEL is a message that's sent with SendMessage().  That requires a different hook, WH_CALLWNDPROC or WH_CALLWNDPROCRET.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I guess you mean MSG* pmsg = (MSG*)lParam, right?
But it's not working, The "Beep" never gets called. If I move the "Beep" before the "if (pmsg->message == EM_REPLACESEL)" it works. But Spy++ shows that EM_REPLACESEL is comming in as a messages, so I should be called in your example. Any hints on what's wrong?

Comment: Right.  Come to think of it, you appear to use the wrong hook.  Answer updated.

Comment: Changed it to a CallWndProc CALLBACK function (and changed the SetWindowsHook to g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, g_hInstDll, npThreadId), but I have the same problem = no beep (Also tried it with CallWndRetProc)

Comment: @TheisKristensen: The `lParam` of a [`CallWndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644975.aspx) hook is not a `MSG*`, it is a `CWPSTRUCT*` instead. Did you take that into account when you changed your code? `CWPSTRUCT *cwps = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam; if (cwps->message == EM_REPLACESEL) { ... }`. `MSG` and `CWPSTRUCT` contain the message ID at different field offsets.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally do it.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(MSG nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
   while(GetMessage(&nCode, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
   {
      if(nCode.message == EM_REPLACESEL)
      {
         //Do something
      }
      else
         DispatchMessage(&nCode);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ayesha. But I this compatible a SetWindowsHook (HOOKPROC) and what about the CallNextHookEx function in the CALLBACK function?